# WSL.exe and ubuntu.exe are different

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I run `wsl.exe` or `bash.exe`, I have following image as output:

[image: opening wsl]

Now when I run `ubuntu.exe` using start menu or typing `ubuntu1804` in cmd I have this:

[image: opening ubuntu]

They have different configs of the shell, apps, etc.
Is this expected to happen?

How can I make all of them loaded with one configuration?

**Note** `termin` is a simple alias to load `terminator` (set in `ubuntu.exe`)

Comment: Does this occur without Terminator and `/bin/bash` as default shell?

Comment: No, default is zsh

Comment: basically wsl.exe (bash.exe) is deprecated according to github posts, but possible workaround has been suggested on [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/3627#issuecomment-435618092)

Comment: Could you output `echo $0` and `echo $SHELL` to check if you have the same shell in all cases? Also `echo $PATH` to see how the paths differ. That should help track down where the change might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can view your current wslconfig by running

```
wslconfig /l
```

I saw that I had the Legacy one as default, whereas the "ubuntu" one was second. I unregistered the legacy by running

```
wslconfig /u legacy
```

Comment: CAREFUL: unregistering a distro on WSL DELETES ALL YOUR DATA, SETTINGS AND SOFTWARE ASSOCIATED WITH IT. I discovered it too late. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config